# How can I see HTTP Request in socket C

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm trying to see the HTTP request to my socket server.  When I request from browser this server, naturally, response is invalid because there is no HTTP response here. But I want to see this HTTP request on my terminal screen. How can I do this, any idea?

It is simply multithreded socket server code:

```
void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *((int*)socket_desc);   
    char *message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";;

    //Send some messages to the client
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    message = "Its my duty to communicate with you";
    write(sock , message , strlen(message));

    free(socket_desc); //Free the socket pointer     
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc, new_socket, c, *new_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char *message;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        puts("Could not create socket");
        return 1;
    }

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(8888);

    if(bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("Binding failed");
        return 1;
    }
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while((new_socket = 
           accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");
        message = "Hello Client, I will assign a handler for you\n";
        write(new_socket, message, strlen(message));

        pthread_t sniffer_thread;
        new_sock = malloc(1); // a memory allocator
        *new_sock = new_socket;

        if(pthread_create(&sniffer_thread, NULL, connection_handler,
                          (void*)new_sock) < 0)
        {
            puts("Could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just read from the socket?

Comment: You are not reading anything from the client you accept, so you have no opportunity to output the request data to your terminal. Also, all of your `write()`s are violating the HTTP protocol. And your `malloc()` for `new_sock` is too small (1 byte, where `sizeof(int)` bytes are needed instead)

Comment: Just run wireshark or tcpdump